# Magento 2: How to get JSON API Variable in Model

Tags: magento2, model, rest-api, variables, json

Below is the REST API called on Checkout Page, when you have multiple address & u click on "Ship here"

**magento/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods-by-address-id**

It passes `addressId` variable as a POST

How to get that variable in Model?

**magento\vendor\magento\module-dhl\Model\Carrier.php**

```
protected function _buildQuotesRequestXml() {
    // Need to get addressId variable here
}
```

I need it because for Hong Kong it's not passing City for Saved Address.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7928